# Conditionally add styles properties on MUI

Tags: material-ui, styled-components

On `styled-components` we can have something like this

```
import syled, { css } from 'styled-components';
const StyledButton = styled.button<StyledButtonProps>`
    display: flex;
    ${textStyles.styledButton}
    ${props =>
        props.disabled &&
        css`
            opacity: 0.5;
        `}
`
```

I'm trying to use MUI's `styled` but can't find how to conditionally add the `opacity` property based on the props passed to the button. I'm trying something like this, but don't want to define the default value of every conditional styles as on `opacity` here (since there could be a LOT of conditional properties based on the value of a passed prop)

```
import { styled } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
const StyledMUIButton = styled(({ disabled, disclosure, whiteButton, fullWidth, noMarginTop, ...rest }: StyledButtonProps) => (
    <button {...rest} />
))({
    display: 'flex',
    ...textStyles.button,
    opacity: (props: StyledButtonProps) => props.disabled ? 0.5 : 1
})
```

Another case would be something like this in `styled-components`, how can be that applied to MUI's `styled`?

```
    ${props =>
        props.whiteButton
            ? css`
                  background-color: transparent;
                  border: none;
                  ${textStyles.styledLink}
              `
            : css`
                  &:focus {
                      background: transparent;
                      border: 1px solid ${colors.textLink};
                      color: ${colors.textLink};
                  }
              `}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [`makeStyles`](https://material-ui.com/es/styles/basics/#hook-api) the following way

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    button: (props: StyledButtonProps) => ({
        display: 'flex',
        ...textStyles.button,
        ...props.disabled && { opacity: 0.5 },
    })
})
```